# Case Class that extends play.api.mvc.WrappedRequest doesn't have the copy method

Tags: scala

I have a case class

```
case class Oauth2Request[A](
  foo: String,
  request: Request[A]
) extends WrappedRequest[A](request) {
    def bar = foo
}
```

(That's play.api.mvc.WrappedRequest) Later instantiated with

```
val wrappedRequest = Oauth2Request("foo",otherRequest)
val publicApiRequest = wrappedRequest.copy(request=apiRequest)
```

comes out like this in my ide [image: autocompletion]

The end result looks like [image: error] with compile error

```
not found: value request
```

Why does the copy method bring up arguments that look like the constructor to WrappedRequest instead of the copy method I am expecting which can be used to copy/alter 1 or more fields of the original object?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.WrappedRequest) `WrappedRequest` is *not* a case class. But it does have a copy method, as your IDE shown you, but none of these arguments are named `request`.

Since the constructor of the class takes one argument of type `Request`, why not just `new WrappedRequest(apiRequest)`?

Comment: The case class I created extends WrappedRequest though, I would expect that my abstraction would have copy. An alternative, like you said, is to do Oauth2Request("foobar", apiRequest) but there are actually many more field than what I showed here and the scala way is to go the terse route (less code). Would you know why my case class (Oauth2Request) doesn't have the copy method? I believe I had read all case classes have a copy method